# How to stop alertify.js from "bouncing" when it opens

Tags: javascript, alertifyjs

I'm using [alertify.js](https://alertifyjs.com/)

I love its options, but there is one thing I really dislike. When the modal opens, it "bounces".
Run any examples [here](https://alertifyjs.com/) to see an example.

I can't see any way to turn this off.
Is there something I'm missing? How can I have the modal dialogs show without bouncing?

Comment: You should be able to change transitions, or disable transitions all together.

Comment: I knew it had to be simple. Thanks

Comment: alertify.dialog('alert').set({transition:'fade',message: 'Transition effect: fade'}).show();